# Understanding Diffeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

As far as I know a diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map which is bijective.

But I do not get why its inverse is also smooth. What are the examples of homomorphisms which are not diffeomorphisms?

Further under what conditions is a smooth map $F: M\to N$ a diffeomorphism?

I am not able to understand because I cannot find examples with counterexamples.

Edit and a note to myself.

A diffeomorphism is a smooth bijective map whose inverse is also smooth.for a bijective smooth map, it doesn't imply that the inverse is smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "classic" example of a smooth homeomorphism which is not a diffeomorphism is $x \mapsto x^3 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This function is clearly smooth and bijective, and its inverse $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, but this inverse function is not differentiable at $0$!

To answer your second question:

**Fact** Let $f : M \to N$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds. The following are equivalent:
(i) $f$ is a diffeomorphism;
(ii) $f$ is a bijective local diffeomorphism.

$x \mapsto x^3 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and bijective, but not a local diffeomorphism, because its derivative is $0$ at $0$. So, it fails condition (ii).

Comment: yes, I got the definition wrong.

Comment: Good job correcting your understanding! Hope this helped.

Comment: why a bijective local diffeomorphisms are diffeomorphisms?

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem? If so, you can prove this in a couple lines. Try to write your proof as directly as possible: assume that $f : M \to N$ is a bijective local diffeomorphism, and then show that $f^{-1}$ is smooth at each point in $N$.